# JSON String Parsing & List Elements Binding to DataGrid c# in winform

Tags: c#, json, winforms, datagridview

I'm looking for a solution to bind the json response to datagrid in winform. I have been trying last 3 days but no way its going well.

My c# class for json

```
public class RootObject
{
    public List<string> uid { get; set; }
    public List<string> email { get; set; }
    public List<string> join { get; set; }
    public List<string> mobile { get; set; }
    public List<string> name { get; set; }
    public List<string> state { get; set; }
    public List<string> district { get; set; }
    public List<string> address { get; set; }
    public List<string> pincode { get; set; }
    public List<string> balance { get; set; }
    public bool error { get; set; }
    public string error_msg { get; set; }
}
```

my json response -

```
{"uid":["58924a301801e2.01873036","58c12008715ac3.83978983","58c2c524060d34.25876386","58c61faae8abd4.23607623"],"email":["ing@gmail.com","lemarg@gmail.com","aji@gmail.com","grt@gmail.com"],"join":["2017-02-02 02:20:56","2017-03-09 09:27:40","2017-03-10 15:24:25","2017-03-13 00:00:00"],"mobile":["2147483647","2147483647","214748897","7002352089"],"name":["saurabh saikia","RATUL BHUYAN","AZHAR UDDIN","mon saikia"],"state":["assam","assam","ASSAM","assam"],"district":["jorhat","Jorhat","NAGAON","jrt"],"address":["jorhat","Jorhat","BAGARIGURI, JURIA","jrt"],"pincode":["785001","785001","785001","123456"],"balance":["1.4500","0.0000","0.0000","0.0000"],"error":false,"error_msg":"User Sucessfully Registred "}
```

On button click event after calling the web services i deserialize response and tried adding to datagrid using -

```
var jsonlist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonResponse);

DataRow rows = this.USER_TABLE.NewRow();

USER_TABLE.Rows.Add(jsonlist.uid.ToArray());
USER_TABLE.Rows.Add(jsonlist.email.ToArray());
USER_TABLE.Rows.Add(jsonlist.join.ToArray());
USER_TABLE.Rows.Add(jsonlist.mobile.ToArray());
USER_TABLE.Rows.Add(jsonlist.name.ToArray());
USER_TABLE.Rows.Add(jsonlist.state.ToArray());
USER_TABLE.Rows.Add(jsonlist.district.ToArray());
USER_TABLE.Rows.Add(jsonlist.address.ToArray());
USER_TABLE.Rows.Add(jsonlist.pincode.ToArray());
USER_TABLE.Rows.Add(jsonlist.balance.ToArray());
```

i am attaching the output - [DataGridView with data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WLCI.jpg)

Comment: If it's not working, what's actually happening?

Comment: its adding the values to column instead of row say --- uid  email join  all the column are filled by uid

Comment: Can you add the code where you are binding to the datagrid?

Comment: I think some code is missing to really say what's going on (or the exception)

That said, an older video of mine using PopulateObject (which I like) from NewtonSoft's Json classes actually may help you (there is another one somewhere too with Datagrids... 
https://youtu.be/j28OXdlJ2EI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

code which adds data to DataTable is incorrect. Each row should contains one element from each of List properties

```
var jsonlist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonResponse);

for(int i=0; i < jsonlist.uid.Count; i++)
    USER_TABLE.Rows.Add(
            jsonlist.uid[i],
            jsonlist.email[i],
            jsonlist.join[i],
            jsonlist.mobile[i],
            jsonlist.name[i],
            jsonlist.state[i],
            jsonlist.district[i],
            jsonlist.address[i],
            jsonlist.pincode[i],
            jsonlist.balance[i]);
```